# Basic Hello World Project Weblogic10.3 in Eclipse with JSF 1.2

Tags: eclipse, jsf, weblogic, jsf-1.2

I usualy use Tomcat and I am suprised how hard it it to get a JSF project running in WL. I need a basic hello world project to run with Weblogic 10.3, JSF 1.2 and Eclipse Indigo. What I have done:

1st Added the WL Server in eclipse (nothing you can do wrong there)
2nd Created a dynamic web project with the following config (see print screen).
[image]

I let everything on default, here is JSF config.
[image]

3rd I ran the project on the server and received the following stacktrace:
[image]
Maybe the print screen is unreadable, the revelant error msg is:

```
    INFO: Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_03-b04-FCS) for context '/footwo'
    28.03.2014 11:22:18 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory getProviderInstance
    SCHWERWIEGEND: JSF1030: The specified InjectionProvider implementation 'com.bea.faces.WeblogicInjectionProvider' cannot be loaded.
    28.03.2014 11:22:18 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
```

I also googled and checked everything people sayd about the error. If I check on the WL Console from the server, I see that JSF 1.2 was successfully deployed so I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Please, don't provide stack traces in image format. Just copy-paste them as you do below.

Comment: Could you post the entire thread as text instead of just the last few lines?

Comment: When does the error occur. Also if you open up the images in a new tab "Right Click -> Open in new tab" they are much bigger and more legible. Are you just not including faces in your URL like here: http://www.albinsblog.com/2012/08/javalangruntimeexception-cannot-find.html#.UzWyRfmwKaI

Answer (score 1):

The problem somehow was another war file on the server where we tried to use jsf2.2 on WL 10.3 server. After I removed this instance and restarted and redeployed the jsf1.2 project worked. The comment from "better_use_mkstemp" above also helped to render jsf syntax, because eclipse per default opens a browser without /faces in the url, which can be a bit misleading.